# Create an Observable you can unsubscribe from in RxCpp

Tags: c#, c++, system.reactive, rxcpp

I'm porting some code from C# that heavily relies on Rx, and I have difficulties finding C++ equivalents to some of the most used C# methods.

In particular, I want to create an observable from the subscription/unsubscription logic. In C#, I use the [`Observable.Create<TSource> Method (Func<IObserver<TSource>, Action>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229122(v=vs.103).aspx) override to create an observable. For instance

```
var observable = Observable.Create<int>(observer =>
{
    observers.Add(observer);
    return () =>
    {
        observers.Remove(observer)
    };
});
```

Is it possible to do the same with [RxCpp](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp)? I think the answer lies in the `rx::observable<>::create(OnSubscribe os)` method, but I can't figure out how to use it to "register" an unsubscription lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In RxCpp and RxJava .subscribe() takes a subscriber. A subscriber is a subscription and an observer bound together.

In RxCpp your example might look like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::list<rxcpp::subscriber<int>>> observers(new std::list<rxcpp::subscriber<int>>());

auto observable = rxcpp::observable<>::create<int>([=](rxcpp::subscriber<int> out){
    auto it = observers->insert(observers->end(), out);
    it->add([=](){
        observers->erase(it);
    });
});
```

NOTE: `rxcpp::subscriber<int>` is a type-forgetter that hides the type of the observer. This allows it to be stored in a collection, but introduces virtual functions for on_next, on_error and on_completed.

Comment: So you register the callback on the subscriber object instead of returning it. Now I get it, thank you a lot.